# Яндекс-Карты. Узнать название ближайшей остановки общественного транспорта

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, можно ли получить ближайшую остановку общественного транспорта при известных координатах места, рядом с которым надо искать. Прямо сейчас вижу в документации карт способ найти ближайшее, например, метро или ближайшую улицу:

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
// создание карты
let map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.75, 37.6],
    zoom: 14
})

// обработчик кликов по карте
map.events.add('click', e => {
    // поиск ближайшей станции метро
    var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode(e.get('coords'), {kind: 'metro'});
    myGeocoder.then((res) => {
        // когда ближайшее метро найдено, вывести имя станции
        var nearest = res.geoObjects.get(0);
        var name = nearest.properties.get('name');
        alert(name)
    })
})
```

})

Но что насчет автобусных остановок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищите метод [`nearest_stations`](https://yandex.ru/dev/rasp/doc/reference/query-nearest-station.html?lang=ru). Вызовите его с параметром `station_types=bus_stop` для того, чтобы получить автобусные остановки. Название станции содержится в параметре `title`.

***Синтаксис запроса:***

```html
https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/nearest_stations/ ?
  apikey=<ключ> 
& lat=<широта>
& lng=<долгота>
& distance=<радиус охвата>
& [lang=<язык>]
& [offset=<сдвиг относительно первого рейса в ответе>]
& [limit=<ограничение на количество рейсов в ответе>]
& [station_types=<тип станции>]
& [transport_types=<тип транспортного средства>]
& [format=<формат>]
```